# Debugging Scrapy Item pipeline

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I am trying to persist the scraped items into MySQL running on localhost. Even tough the spider crawls the sites and scrapes items in the intended way, my pipeline object for persisting does not work - it does not store items into the database.

PersistMySQL class in the pipelines.py file:

```
class PersistMySQL(object):

    con = None
    cur = None
    query = "INSERT INTO table(title, description, price) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)"

    def __init__(self):
        self.setupDBCon()

    def __del__(self):
        self.con.close()

    def setupDBCon(self):
        self.con = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                                   user='root',
                                   passwd='mypass',
                                   db='mydb')
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()

    def process_items(self, item):
        try:
            self.cur.execute(self.query, (item['Title'], item['Desc'], item['Price']))
            self.con.commit()
        except Error as err:
            print err
```

It does not print the exception block so it seems that my query is valid.
The following code is located in settings.py (along with other settings):

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
'myScraper.pipelines.CleanHTMLPipeline': 100,
'myScraper.pipelines.CleanStringPipeline': 200,
'myScraper.pipelines.PersistMySQL': 300
}
```

I use the scrapy shell and find it very useful but it seems that there is no way to debug the item pipeline from the shell and using excepts that would print MySQL errors does not help. The spider closes down with no errors and with a sensible number of items crawled that **should** be persisted to the database.

Comment: Can you reformat your code using the `{}` button from the editor's toolbar?

Comment: The signature for the main item-saving method of an item pipeline is [`process_item(self, item, spider)`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#process_item), not `process_items(self, item)`

Comment: That was the problem, that and process_item needs to return a dict or item. @paultrmbrth what part of my question should i reformat and I would like to mark this question answered...?